# VBA Excel Type Mismatch (Lines and Dots Game)

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently making the Lines and Dots (or Dots and Boxes) game in VBA Excel and keep running into the "Type Mismatch" error. I have set the fill cell colors to RGB(0,0,0) for Black but when I go to create the criteria to exit game, when the boxes are filled, I get "Type Mismatch".

```
Sub Main()
'Start routine to fill boxes with player color when complete
 'Declare & Initialize Player scores
   Dim Player1Score As Long
   Dim Player2Score As Long
   Dim TurnNum As Long
   Dim Turn As String
   Dim InGame As Boolean

  InGame = True
  Turn = "Odd"

    If (TurnNum Mod 2 = 0) Then
        Turn = "Odd"
        'MsgBox ("Odd")
    Else
        Turn = "Even"
        'MsgBox ("Even")
    End If

Do While (InGame = True)
    If (Range("E4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("E5") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("E5") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If
    ElseIf (Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("G5") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("G5") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("H5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("I5") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("I5") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("J5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("K5") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("K5") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("E7") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("E7") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("G6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("G7") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("G7") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("I6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("I7") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("I7") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("K6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("K7") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("K7") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("E9") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("E9") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("G8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("G9") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("G9") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("I8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("I9") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("I9") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("K8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("K9") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("K9") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("E10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("E11") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("E11") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("G10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("G11") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("G11") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("I10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("I11") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("I11") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If

    ElseIf (Range("K10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
        If (Turn = "Odd") Then
            Player1Score = Player1Score + 1
            Range("K11") = Player1
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        ElseIf (Turn = "Even") Then
            Player2Score = Player2Score + 1
            Range("K11") = Player2
            TurnNum = TurnNum + 1
        End If
    End If

    If ((Range("E4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("H5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("J5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K4").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L5").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("G6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("I6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("K6").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("G8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("I8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("K8").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("E10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("D11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("E12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("G10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("F11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("G12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("I10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("H11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("I12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) & _
        (Range("K10").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("J11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("K12").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) & Range("L11").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0))) Then

       InGame = False

    End If
Loop
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I have another module that is assigned to rectangles so when you click on said rectangle, that cell color changes to black (RGB (0,0,0))

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: **On which line code code does the error occur ??**

Comment: When I run the Debugger, it sows the error with the giant If block that is supposed to change InGame to False and exit the loop.

Comment: select the whole big block at the end -> ctrl+H -> change `&` to `And` for selected range. your `&` just chains the true up `truetruetrue....`

Comment: Should the above If statements be changed as well?

Comment: @Shark Yes they should

Comment: Thanks Guys. No more error. My program just doesn't respond now. hahaha Probably shouldn't run so many applications at once.